# How to send email to Entreprise Connect folder with VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook, mapi, livelink, opentext

I need to send e-mails to entreprise connect (content server) from outlook. E-mails go in specific project folders already created in Content Server. The user click e-mail and click link, they enter the project number and a function find the LiveLink ID, create the path and put the e-mail there. Everything used to work perfectly with LiveLink, but since recent changes to Content Server, nothing works.

```
dim FP as mapifolder
dim folder as mapifolder

Set FP = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("LiveLink")
'Set FP = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("Entreprise Connect") //not working
For Each folder In FP.Folders
        If fold.name Like "*GGG*" Then //We search for our division's folder within livelink
            Set FP = folder
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

For i = 0 To UBound(path) - 1
        Set FP = FP.Folders(path(i)) //path(0) = "ProjectXXX/", path(1) = "Budget/", etc
    Next
End If
```

So this code used to work with LiveLink, now that we use Entreprise Connect, it doesn't. 
See image, I don't know if it's not considered as a folder or something else, FP is always "nothing" whenever I look at it during debug.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVdGE.png

PS: I didn't do the first code, I'm just supposed to make it work now. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!

I removed the search for GGG and hardcoded the name. the search fucntion was used to take care of the folder name change, when offline the server name becomes "Livelink GGG-12 (offline)".

It appears that I made a typo error also in one of the variable.

Set FP = Application.Session.Folders("Enterprise Connect").Folders("Livelink GGG-12")